# I am creating the textView Dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

I want to set the hello text in center after completion of running the code as  I am creating the text view dynamically.

```
TextView textView;
private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
     textView = new TextView(this)
     textView.setText(" hello ");
     textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}
```

Comment: this code is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(LinearLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: how to make use of addRule

Answer (score 0):

Use :
`textView.setTextAlignment(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`